# What determines Java object size?

Tags: java, memory-management

What contributes to the size of a single object in memory?

I know that primitives and references would, but is there anything else? 
Would the number of methods and the length of them matter?

Comment: use jmap and you will see. what contributes: the fields of course. *Would the number of methods and the length of them matter?* only the overridden ones may take space once in the virtual table.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is completely implementation-dependent, but there are a few factors that influence object size in Java.

First, the number and types of the fields in the Java object definitely influence space usage, since you need to have at least as much storage space as is necessary to hold all of the object's fields.  However, due to padding, alignment, and pointer compression optimizations, there is no direct formula you can use to compute precisely how much space is being used this way.

As for methods, typically speaking the number of methods in an object has no impact on its size.  Methods are often implemented using a feature called [virtual function tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) (or "vtables") that make it possible to invoke methods through a base class reference in constant time.  These tables are usually stored by having a single instance of the vtable shared across multiple objects, then having each object store a single pointer to the vtable.

Interface methods complicate this picture a bit, because there are several different implementations possible.  One implementation adds a new vtable pointer for each interface, so the number of interfaces implemented may affect object size, while others do not.  Again, it's implementation dependent how things are actually put together in memory, so you can't know for certain whether or not this will have a memory cost.

To the best of my knowledge there are no implementations of the JVM in existence today in which the length of a method influences the size of an object.  Typically, only one copy of each method is stored in memory, and the code is then shared across all instances of a particular object.  Having longer methods might require more *total* memory, but should not impact the per-object memory for instances of a class.  That said, the JVM spec makes no promises that this must be the case, but I can't think of a reasonable implementation that would expend extra space per object for method code.

In addition to fields and methods, many other factors could contribute to the size of an object.  Here's a few:

Depending on what type of garbage collector (or collectors) that the JVM is using, each object might have extra storage space to hold information about whether the object is live, dead, reachable, etc.  This can increase storage space, but it's out of your control.  In some cases, the JVM might optimize object sizes by trying to store the object on the stack instead of the heap.  In this case, the overhead may not even be present for some types of objects.

If you use synchronization, the object might have extra space allocated for it so that it can be synchronized on.  Some implementations of the JVM don't create a monitor for an object until it's necessary, so you may end up having smaller objects if you don't use synchronization, but you cannot guarantee that this will be the case.

Additionally, to support operators like `instanceof` and typecasting, each object may have some space reserved to hold type information.  Typically, this is bundled with the object's vtable, but there's no guarantee that this will be true.

If you use assertions, some JVM implementations will create a field in your class that contains whether or not assertions are enabled.  This is then used to disable or enable assertions at runtime.  Again, this is implementation-specific, but it's good to keep in mind.

If your class is a nonstatic inner class, it may need to hold a reference to the class that contains it so that it can access its fields.  However, the JVM might optimize this away if you never end up using this.

If you use an anonymous inner class, the class may need to have extra space reserved to hold the `final` variables that are visible in its enclosing scope so that they can be referenced inside the class.  It's implementation-specific whether this information is copied over into the class fields or just stored locally on the stack, but it can increase object size.

Some implementations of `Object.hashCode()` or `System.identityHashCode(Object)` may require extra information to be stored in each object that contains the value of that hash code if it can't compute it any other way (for example, if the object can be relocated in memory).  This might increase the size of each object.

Comment: *It's implementation-specific whether this information is copied over into the class fields or just stored locally on the stack, but it can increase object size.* It cannot be stored on the stack unless the entire object can be optimized away and not be allocated.

Comment: @templatetypedef just to clear does java use vtable for dynamic dispatch ?

Comment: @peter That's up to the implementation. To the best of my knowledge, Java implementations typically use a single vtable for normal inheritance, but have a secondary mechanism in place for dynamic dispatch done through interfaces (the bytecode has different instructions for these cases, leading me to believe that they probably were done differently). However, this is purely up to the implementer and they could alternatively use techniques like polymorphic inline caching in addition to or in place of vtables.

Answer (score 7):

To add a bit of (admittedly vague) data to @templatetypedef's excellent answer.  These numbers are for typical recent 32-bit JVMs, but they are *implementation specific*:

- The header overhead for each object *typically* 2 words for a regular object and 3 words for an array.  The header includes GC related flags, and some kind of pointer to the object's actual class.  For an array, an extra word is needed to hold the array size.
- If you've called (directly or indirectly) `System.identityHashCode()` on an object, and it has survived a GC cycle, then add an extra word to store the hashcode value.  (Modern JVMs use a clever trick to avoid reserving a hashcode header field for *all* objects ...)
- The storage allocation granularity *may be* a multiple of words; e.g. 2.
- Fields of an object are typically word aligned; i.e. they are not packed.
- Elements of an array of a primitive type are packed, but booleans are typically represented by a byte in packed form.
- References occupy 4 bytes both as fields and as array elements.

Things are a bit more complicated for 64-bit JVMs because of pointer compression (OOPS) in some JVMs.  Also, I'm not sure if fields 32 or 64 bit aligned.

---

(Note: the above are based on what I've heard / read in various places from various "knowledgeable people".  There is no definitive source for this kind of information apart from Oracle / Sun, and (AFAIK) they haven't published anything.)

Comment: *Also, I'm not sure if fields 32 or 64 bit aligned.* 32, or it will disaster w/ int. As for alignment there is more info but in order to SSE vector intrinsic (for instance: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/hotspot-comp/hotspot/rev/fbde8ec322d0 ) some arrays might further be aligned to 128 bit boundaries. There is another RFE about SSE, dunno if it has been incorporate in java7 already.

Answer (score 4):

Check out java.sizeOf in sourceforge here: http://sizeof.sourceforge.net/

Comment: GPL license rather than LGPL makes that either unusable or extremely inconvenient (if selectively compiled in/out) for proprietary applications.

Comment: I think it's fine for learning purposes, which I believe is the intension of the question.

Comment: @Jason S - that's one of the disadvantages of developing applications that are not GPL licensed.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, in HBase source code, there is some caculation about object size based on the some common known rules how different fields occupies the spaces. And it will be different in 32bit or 64bit OS. At least above people all know. But I didn't look into details why they do that. But they really did it in the source code.

Besides,Java.lang.intrument.Intrumentation Class can do it also by getObjectSize(). I guess the open source project is also based on it.
In this link,there is details of how to use it.
[In Java, what is the best way to determine the size of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object)

As a comment. Actually I am also interested in if you do it in the source code, what will be the most meaningful use case?