# What is the size of the object in java

Tags: java, oop

As we all know that java uses the following data types

```
byte    Occupy 8 bits in memory
short   Occupy 16 bits in memory
int     Occupy 32 bits in memory
long    Occupy 64 bits in memory
```

If I create a class like

```
class Demo{
    byte b;        
    int i;
    long l;
}

Demo obj = new Demo();
```

Now my question is `obj` size is `< or > or =` the size of `b+i+l` which is `104 bytes`. Please give me the clarification with proper reason.

Thanks,
Anil Kumar C

Comment: Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html it will help you to approximately measure size of your objects.

Comment: how can instrumentation help?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object to know how to calculate the size of the object in memory

Comment: You can take a look at this: [Almost Same Question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060141/what-determines-java-object-size

Comment: it contains method getObjectSize for estimating object size. Here is the example of usage: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/instrumentation.shtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The in-memory size of the object depends on the architecture, mainly on whether the VM is 32 or 64-bit. The actual VM implementation also matters.

For each object, you need space for its object header (typically 2*8 bytes on 64-bit VMs), its fields (extra space for alignment depending on the VM implementation). The final space is then rounded up to the nearest multiple of the word size.

Comment: silly question of the day: and what about method references? Are they in the object or not ? if so, for each method, we should add size of its reference.

Comment: @BigMike: generally, method references are part of the class object, not the instantiated objects. Of course, HotSpot-based VMs are free to complicate things up at their leisure...

Comment: so basically at least a reference to the virtual table (can I use this term?) has to sum up to the object size or does the VM keeps completely separated object instances and classes ? - classes used improperly in my sentence -

Comment: @BigMike: IIRC, part of the header of each object is a reference to its corresponding class object. The method references are *not* duplicated for each new instance...

Comment: Object allocation is 8-byte aligned in 32-bit and 64-bit JVMs.

Answer (score 8):

From http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml

> 1. a bare Object takes up 8 bytes;
> 2. an instance of a class with a single boolean field takes up 16 bytes: 8 bytes of header, 1 byte for the boolean and 7 bytes of
>      "padding" to make the size up to a multiple of 8;
> 3. an instance with eight boolean fields will also take up 16 bytes: 8 for the header, 8 for the booleans; since this is already a multiple
>      of 8, no padding is needed;
> 4. an object with a two long fields, three int fields and a boolean will take up:
>
>    - 8 bytes for the header;
>    - 16 bytes for the 2 longs (8 each);
>    - 12 bytes for the 3 ints (4 each);
>    - 1 byte for the boolean;
>    - a further 3 bytes of padding, to round the total up from 37 to 40, a multiple of 8.

Comment: This is more accurate answer than what has been accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say that will be the size of obj in memory, type size indication help the developers but actually in the memory it's a bit different. I advise you to read [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip130.html?page=1), it's really interesting.

Answer (score 1):

First, you confused bits and bytes.

Second, it will also need pointer to "vtable", where information about its class is stored. It will, most likely, be 4 bytes (32 bits) on 32bit systems and 8 bytes on 64bit sytems.

Finally, note that due to memory fragmentation, total program memory might be higher than sum of all objects.

Comment: +1 I was just wondering how method references comes into play.

Answer (score 0):

The header of an object can take 8 bytes on a 32-bit JVM and 12 bytes on a 32-bit JVM.

Each primitive takes the number of bits (not bytes you indicate)

Object allocation is 8 byte aligned so there is up to 7 bytes of padding at the end of a object. i.e. the space actually used is rounded up to the next multiple of 8.

```
class Demo{ // 8 or 12 bytes
    byte b; // 1 byte
    int i;  // 4 bytes
    long l; // 8 bytes
}

Demo obj = new Demo();
```

So the size of the object can take 24 bytes on a 32-bit JVM and 32 bytes on a 64-bit JVM.

Comment: `The header of an object can take 8 bytes on a 32-bit JVM and 12 bytes on a 32-bit JVM` Whats the difference then?